# OnFocusChangeListener locks gui

Tags: android, android-edittext, onfocus

I have an editText in my application and I'm adding a listener like in code below

```
if(edit!=null){
        edit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {            
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {           
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if( paramKey!=null){

                    if(!hasFocus){
                    if(edit.getText()!=null)
                        dataModel.updateParamsValue(paramKey, edit.getText().toString());
                    }

                }
            }

        });
    }
```

When I focus to my editText and enter a text it locks gui, do I miss something?

Comment: does your dataModel.update ... method return ?

Comment: i think updateParamsValue() locks gui and not OnFocusChangeListener.. make sure to put updateParamsValue() in background process if it is communicating with server or internet..

Comment: updateParamsValue is a very simple operation and returns nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is dataModel.updateParamsValue a heavy operation? Your listener works in the UI thread, so it will lock the UI till it completes. Try changing code like this:

```
if(edit.getText()!=null)
                v.post(new Runnable(){
                    dataModel.updateParamsValue(paramKey, edit.getText().toString());
                });
            }
```

Comment: it's actually a very simple operation, I use this in lots of places, the problem is I can't see what I typed too